# datetime: split a month 10-day periods

Tags: php, date, mktime

I send a earlier date and it returns me the periods between the earlier date and today cut by tens of days.

> Example with 14/01/2016

**I need the result to be exactly as below:**

- 11 Jan 2016 to 20 Jan 2016
- 21 Jan 2016 to 31 Jan 2016
- 01 Feb 2016 to 10 Feb 2016
- 11 Feb 2016 to 20 Feb 2016
- 21 Feb 2016 to 29 Feb 2016
- 01 Mar 2016 to 10 Mar 2016
- 11 Mar 2016 to 20 Mar 2016
- 21 Mar 2016 to 31 Mar 2016
- 01 Apr 2016 to 10 Apr 2016
- 11 Apr 2016 to 20 Apr 2016

**Here my code:**

```
function date_interval($startTime = false){

    if( ! $startTime){

        return array();
    } else {

    if(date('d',$startTime) < 10){
        $actual = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',$startTime), 1, date('Y',$startTime));
    } elseif(date('d',$startTime) < 20){
        $actual = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',$startTime), 10, date('Y',$startTime));
    } else {
        $actual = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',$startTime), 20, date('Y',$startTime));
    }

    if(date('d',time()) < 10) {
        $target = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',time()), 10, date('Y',time()));
    } elseif(date('d',time()) < 20) {
        $target = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',time()), 20, date('Y',time()));
    } else {
        $target = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',time())+1, 1, date('Y',time()));
    }


    $current = $actual;
    $last = $actual;

    while($current < $target) {

        if(date('d',$current) < 10){
            $current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',$current), 10, date('Y',$current));
        } elseif(date('d',$current) < 20){
            $current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',$current), 20, date('Y',$current)); 
        } else {
            $current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',$current)+1, 1, date('Y',$current));
        } 
        $dateTime[date("Y-m-d", $last) .'~'. date("Y-m-d", $current)] = date('d M Y',$last) . ' - ' . date('d M Y',$current));
        $last = $current;
        }
    }
    return $dateTime;
}
```

Comment: You must hate yourself to do it this way. Next time use `DateTime()`. *Much* easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime is the darling class from php that solves this type of problem nicely.
Here you feed the startdate to the function as DATETIME object and the function throws back a stack of list tags.

In the loop startDay is beeing modyfied first by adding 10 days to make the jump and then by one to avoid the overlap.
If you want a final line with the (less then ten days) time period from last startDay till today you can add something like:

```
$return .= '<li>From '.$startDay->format('d M Y').' to '.$today->format('d M Y').'</li>';
```

after the loop

```
function date_interval(DATETIME $startDay = NULL)
{
      if( NULL == $startDay){ 
        return array(); }

      $return = '';
      $today = new DATETIME('now');

      while(  $today->diff( $startDay )->format('%a%') > 10  )
      {
          $return .= '<li>From '.$startDay->format('d M Y').' to ';
          $startDay->modify('+10 days');
          $return .= $startDay->format('d M Y').'</li>
          ';
          $startDay->modify('+1 day');
      }
      return $return;
}
```

I altered the above more general solution to do exactly what you describe:

```
    <?php
function date_interval(DATETIME $startDay = NULL)
{
      if( NULL == $startDay){ 
        return array(); }

      $return = '';
      $today = new DATETIME('now');
      $startMonth = new DateTime('first day of '.$startDay->format('M Y') );
      $firstRun = TRUE;

      while(  $today > $startDay )
      {
          $return .= '<li>From '.$startDay->format('d M Y').' to ';
          if( $firstRun == TRUE ){
            if( (int)$startDay->format('d') > 10 )
              $startMonth->modify('+10 days');
            if( (int)$startDay->format('d') > 20 )  
              $startMonth->modify('+10 days');
            $startDay = $startMonth;

            $firstRun = FALSE;
          }
          $lastOfMonth = new DateTime('last day of '.$startDay->format('M Y') );
          if( $lastOfMonth->diff( $startDay )->format('%a%') > 10 )
            $startDay->modify('+9 days');
          else
            $startDay = $lastOfMonth;

          $return .= $startDay->format('d M Y').'</li>
          ';
          $startDay->modify('+1 day');
      }
      return $return;
}

echo date_interval( date_create_from_format('Y-m-d','2016-01-21') )."\n";

?>
```

Comment: Care to explain how this code works? Or how it solves their problem?

Comment: https://eval.in/556397
I explicitely (in the code and the text) said the function is to be used with a datetime object as first parameter.
look into the first line of the function - do you see it now?

Comment: second function gives output as OP requested

Comment: If the start date is higher than 10 there is a tiny mistake on the first date returned (https://eval.in/556507). To facilitate I modified my post, in my example if the start date is 14/01/2016 the first period should be 11/01/2016 to 20/01/2016, so 9 days in less than the end date, all periods must be approximately 9 days. Can you rewrite the code? Thank you very much!

Comment: it should the day (of the first date) is modified by 1,10 or 20. the code doesn't work, I continue to seek :)

Comment: Well, I tried but obviously I fail to understand your wishes properly.

Comment: Ok. I edited your code with my correction. It's done!

Answer (score 0):

See this function using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
function date_interval( $start = Null )
{
    if( !$start ) return array();

    $cur    = new DateTime( sprintf( '%s-%02d', $start->format('Y-m'), [1,11,21,21][ floor(($start->format('j')-1)/10) ] ) );
    $end    = new DateTime();
    $retval = [];

    while( $cur <= $end )
    {
        $key = $cur->format( 'Y-m-d~' );
        $val = $cur->format( 'd M Y - ' );
        if( $cur->format( 'j' ) > 20 ) $cur->modify( 'last day of this month' );
        else                           $cur->modify( '+ 9 days' );
        $retval[ $key.$cur->format( 'Y-m-d' ) ] = $val.$cur->format( 'd M Y' );
        $cur->modify( '+ 1 days' );
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

Calling it in this way:

```
$startDate = '14/01/2016';
$array = date_interval( DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', $startDate ) );
print_r( $array );
```

According with your keys/values schema, the resulting array is:

```
Array
(
    [2016-01-11~2016-01-20] => 11 Jan 2016 - 20 Jan 2016
    [2016-01-21~2016-01-31] => 21 Jan 2016 - 31 Jan 2016
    [2016-02-01~2016-02-10] => 01 Feb 2016 - 10 Feb 2016
    [2016-02-11~2016-02-20] => 11 Feb 2016 - 20 Feb 2016
    [2016-02-21~2016-02-29] => 21 Feb 2016 - 29 Feb 2016
    [2016-03-01~2016-03-10] => 01 Mar 2016 - 10 Mar 2016
    [2016-03-11~2016-03-20] => 11 Mar 2016 - 20 Mar 2016
    [2016-03-21~2016-03-31] => 21 Mar 2016 - 31 Mar 2016
    [2016-04-01~2016-04-10] => 01 Apr 2016 - 10 Apr 2016
    [2016-04-11~2016-04-20] => 11 Apr 2016 - 20 Apr 2016
    [2016-04-21~2016-04-30] => 21 Apr 2016 - 30 Apr 2016
)
```

We operate only on one date (`$cur`), initially created from passed argument; we set the day of month using array `[1,11,21,21]` and selecting key by the rounded down division by 10 of original day (in your example, (14-1)/10 = 1.3, rounded as 1, that is 11 in `[1,11,21,21]` array). This is a quick way to resolve the *31th day* exception.

Then we perform a loop until `$cur` date is greater than today date: we create starting part of key and value, we modify `$cur` adding it nine days or selecting last month's day, we create complete key and value of returned array. At the end of each loop, we increment `$cur` by 1 day.